# gsm character encoding

Tags: php, character-encoding, sms, gsm

in php how can i convert normal text + accented characters in utf8 to gsm format for sending via sms.

Answer (score 0):

There are patches out there that add GSM7 charset support to the GNU iconv library. That should help you. Alternatively, if you just want to do it manually (yick!) you could just retype [this](http://mobiletidings.com/2009/07/06/gsm-7-encoding-gnu-libiconv/) as PHP.